# CSS to define different formats for digits/non-digits

Tags: html, css, xhtml, seam

How do I use CSS to define a text input area where digits and non-digits are rendered with different formats (bold/italic/color)?

i.e.
345 dollar -> *345* **dollar**

Are there anything equivalent to [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/) fo regex for CSS?

*Below are edited*

---

I'm using the Seam framework, any alternatives to achieve this is also welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As svinto already says, this is definitely not possible. Not even, as far as I can see, using an advanced CSS tool like [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/).

You will have to work around by putting the digit into a tag:

```
 <span>345</span> dollar
```

you could of course automate that in a scripting language using Regexes, but I would recommend formatting the output properly instead of relying on such "post-processing", which can break any time when the formatting changes, for example in a different language / locale.

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish this in CSS exclusively. You could use PHP or Javascript to tag content that matches your criteria and style those tags with CSS, however.